# Javascript / Googlescript using set.Formula with complex formulas

Tags: multidimensional-array, google-apps-script, google-sheets, formulas, array-formulas

I have researching this but cannot find a suitable solution. The following formula works fine at the formula level when placed in a sheet cell. The issue is I want the formula to run at the script level. The options I am aware of include running a script to:
(1) set.Formula('=complex formula') 
or
(2) rewriting the entire formula as a script

I am new to GAS, and have messed around with both methods. There seems to be a syntax error when using option (1), usually in the form of a missing ")" that I cannot debug. Employing option (2) is currently above my skill level. Any help on either option would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the formula in question:

> =ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({UI!A:G,YEAR(UI!A:A),MONTH(UI!A:A), TEXT(UI!A:A, "MMMM"), TEXT(UI!A:A, "MMM-YY"), REPLACE(UI!A:A,1,1000,"GRAND
>   TOTAL")}, "SELECT * WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL AND Col2 IS NOT NULL LABEL
>   Col8 'Year',Col9 'MonthMO#',Col10 'MonthMO',Col11 'MonthMOYR',Col12
>   'GRAND TOTAL'"))

Comment: if it only needs to work in newer browsers, you can use `set.Formula(\`=complex formula\`)` syntax (note the grave accents instead of apos/quote) this lets you avoid the toothpick problem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_toothpick_syndrome

Comment: tried set.Formula(`=complex formula`) using chrome version 46.0.2490.80 m. with no luck. The script editor returns "illegal character" error on testing.

Comment: tried set.Formula using grave accents (for some reason i cannot get them to show up in my comment here) using chrome version 46.0.2490.80 m. with no luck. The script editor returns "illegal character" error on testing.

Comment: you need to put that code at the bottom in the grave marks. you can then space it out with linebreaks and not worry as much about nested quotes.

Comment: i used the code with grave marks as you mentioned....the code line will not even save because the source formula has/requires both ' and " within the code, and seems to want to be delimited by " although it is invalid to use " bc it is also part of the code inside. when i use the grave marks instead i still get the illegal character error

Comment: ok i got it. needed to change ' and " to special characters. GAS does not seem to recognize the grave accent. final code: `"=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({UI!A:G, YEAR(UI!A:A), MONTH(UI!A:A), TEXT(UI!A:A, \"MMMM\"), TEXT(UI!A:A, \"MMM-YY\"), REPLACE(UI!A:A,1,1000, \"GRAND TOTAL\")}, \"SELECT * WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL AND Col2 IS NOT NULL LABEL Col8 \'Year\', Col9 \'MonthMO#\',Col10 \'MonthMO\',Col11 \'MonthMOYR\',Col12 \'GRAND TOTAL\'\"))"`

Comment: sorry to send you down a dark alley... i think your problem is with having to balance quotes, the nested syntax itself (like would be in a cell) looks ok...

Answer (score 1):

## Answer

Formulas doesn't run "at script level" so you will have to rewrite your formula as a Google Apps Script / JavaScript function.

## Escaping formula apostrophes in scripts

In case that you want a script to add your complex formula to a cell bear in mind that writing complex formulas in one line makes harder to debug them.
Try dividing your formula by functions and parameters and use a tab to align them. IMHO this prevents that the use of `\` makes the script unreadable ([Leaning toothpick syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_toothpick_syndrome)).

Below is a onEdit() function that inserts the complex formula in the question to the cell to the right of a cell where 'Yes'  is wrote. Look to the use of `\` to escape the apostrophes used in the second parameter of the query function (select statement).

```js
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var rng = ss.getActiveRange();
  var trg = rng.offset(0, 1);
  var formula = 
    '=ARRAYFORMULA('
       + 'QUERY({'
            + 'UI!A:G,YEAR(UI!A:A),MONTH(UI!A:A),' 
            + 'TEXT(UI!A:A, "MMMM"), '
            + 'TEXT(UI!A:A, "MMM-YY"), '
            + 'REPLACE(UI!A:A,1,1000,"GRAND TOTAL")'
          + '},' 
          + '"SELECT * WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL AND Col2 IS NOT NULL LABEL Col8 \'Year\', '
            + 'Col9 \'MonthMO#\', Col10 \'MonthMO\', Col11 \'MonthMOYR\', '
            + 'Col12 \'GRAND TOTAL\'"'
       + ')'
     + ')';
  if(rng.getValue() == 'Yes') trg.setFormula(formula);
}
```